# How to wrap text around a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div around my coinslider. I would like to wrap text around this container div. How does one go about achieving this?

Right now the my HTML is setup like this:

```
<p> <!-- LOTS OF TEXT --> </p>
<div id="mycontainer"> <!-- coinslider inside --></div>
```

My CSS is setup like this:

```
#mycontainer {
position: relative;
float: right;
width: 500;
height: 334;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

```html
<div>
    <div  style="float:left; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 10px; background-color: #ff0000;">
        <!--your image or text--> 
    </div>
    <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
    <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Encase you Div in another div and Give the float property to it ...

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="mycontainer"> <!-- coinslider inside --></div>
</div>
<p> <!-- LOTS OF TEXT --> </p>

#main
{
    float:right;
}
#mycontainer 
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
    background-color:  gold;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/k8NSK/)**

**OR**

P should come after Div

```
   <div id="mycontainer"> <!-- coinslider inside --></div>

    <p> <!-- LOTS OF TEXT --> </p>

#mycontainer 
{
    float:right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
    background-color:  gold;
}
```

**

**[​Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/k8NSK/)**

**

Comment: It works in the fiddle right .. Did you place the p tag after the div tag

Comment: i rearranged it so that the <p> is after the <div> and the only thing that happened was the text shows up under the coinslider now. The text won't wrap around this div.

Comment: If thats the case your other HTML might be affecting its position .. It is difficult to say what exactly is happening unless we know the HTMl structure

Comment: hmm thanks for trying. I think I'm just going to change the layout all together until I have time to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and you should be good:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: hmmm... try putting the whole thing in another div?

Comment: It might be the `position: relative;` statement then. See [this other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380184/wrapping-text-around-a-div-with-css) from stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried removing that too.
hmm thanks for trying. I think I'm just going to change the layout all together until I have time to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mycontainer"> <!-- coinslider inside --><p> <!-- LOTS OF TEXT --> </p></div>
```

Your text needs to go inside the div container. Hope that works.