# Wrap contents of DIV around a DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap the contents of a div around another sibling div (**NOT a nested DIV**)

The code example below comes very close. But what I need is for the contents of the DIV on the left so slide down enough to allow a few lines of the content of the right DIV to flow over the top (as it does on the bottom)

Here is full working HTML doc that demonstrates what is working so far, except for the text flowing on the top.

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}
div.Cover {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  background-color: aqua;
}
div.Content {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="Cover"></div>

  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wrap text around a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296762/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-div)

Comment: Actually read the question. My code example wraps the contents of the div. The question is how to do that and allow the first few lines of the wrapping div to flow over the top of the wrapped div.

Answer (score 0):

If an html solution is enough, just position that div under a few Content divs in the html.

Before:

```
<div class="Cover"></div>
<div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
```

After:

```
<div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="Content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
<div class="Cover"></div>
```

I'm not sure there is a css solution.  Margin-top, top, both clear the space but don't allow floated elements past.

This just means that floated div is relative to the text content, not to the page.

Comment: How is that different then the example code I posted? Do you have a code example?

Comment: Simple example but I think it does what you want.

Comment: No... it simply puts ALL of the text on top of the div that I wrapped

Comment: It's just a code snippet; if you put more content under the 'Cover' div, you will see it fill out as you want.  Any html above 'Cover' will stay above it when the page renders.

Comment: Just move the cover down and let the text sit on top. You'll probably have to tweak it to get the desired look, but doable.

Comment: Elendee: I see what your suggesting now. Thank you for the thought, but it won't help. The HTML is what it is and can't be modified. If I could that, I would simply nest the "cover" div inside the "content" div. 

There are two divs; left and right. I need the right div to flow over the top, to the right, and under the left div. (see code snippet above)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you really want, but can't use yet, are CSS Exclusions: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-exclusions/. They're only supported in IE/Edge as of this writing, and only with the `-ms` prefix.

This article shows some practical examples: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/regions/adobe/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to paste this somewhere, anywhere after the html, this accomplishes the same thing using javascript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.wrapper').prepend($('.Content:nth-of-type(2)'))
</script>
```

Comment: I think you're right, elendee, my solution is either going half to be a bit of jquery, or I'm going to have to re-write the SQL extract the pulls the feed and creates the rendered HTML