# how to make outer lengthy text wrap around & scroll through a fixed/floating <div> without hiding some text behind that <div>

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-ui

In my HTML5 Page there are two things

- Div [strictly fixed to screen]
- Outer Text [lengthy to that much extent that we get scroll bar in browser]

Problem facing:outer text going back div.
Question:How to make outer text align well around fixed div without hiding back.

`div` tag is attributed to `float left` so that text will cover the div.

My requirement is Div **should always appear on screen** and re-sizable so used *CSS* and *jqueryUI* on Div tag to `fixed,adjustable` but unfortunately outer text is going behind div tag which will not happen when we use `position:relative` to *div*.Is there any way to make div fixed to screen and outer text wrap the div safely without hiding.

[Here's a Plunker for my example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/lteW2isY5Lsojv0oROfH?p=preview)

Comment: Nobody is going to click to download that file bro.

Comment: Do you mean, when you resize the `resizable` div, the content should not come out of the div???

Comment: I created a plunker for this:  http://plnkr.co/edit/lteW2isY5Lsojv0oROfH?p=preview.

Comment: Put your text in paragraph tags. ;)

Comment: There is already a question similar to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380184/wrapping-text-around-a-div-with-css

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan is your plunker based off of OP's download?

Comment: I downloaded the file, and can confirm they are the same, yes.

Comment: @Gallen Great, thanks! Updated fiddle coming soon in my answer below...

Comment: @DrydenLong yes, it's the same file.

Comment: Thank you @Dryden Long. is it possible to bring A B C D ..text which are hiding back to wrap well around div making div fixed?

Comment: @venomvendor No,Text is hiding back if div is fixed.i want to wrap all text without hiding and making div fixed

Comment: @kishu See my updated post below. It's possible, but a big headache. I've linked to another SO question that might hold some better resources for you.

Comment: thank you @Dryden Long i will start brute-force but before that i want to confirm shortcut exists.really helpful for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, it's that you are trying to have your text wrap within the `div`. In order to accomplish this, try adding the following CSS to your `div` selector:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

<strike>There may be more to it, but it's hard to tell without the actual CSS and markup. Try including that in your post and we can all get a better idea of how to solve your problem.</strike>

**UPDATE**

Here is a fiddle of my solution in action: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/9n2WP/

**UPDATE #2**

So after getting some clarification from your comment above, it seems you are attempting to wrap the text *around* the `div` rather than inside of it. Fixed positioning doesn't allow you to wrap around the div. There are some "work-arounds" but they are fairly tough to master and might be more trouble than they are worth... You can see this question for more information: [How can I wrap text around a bottom-right div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499829/css-wrap-text-around-a-bottom-right-div)

Comment: [Solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110074/is-it-possible-to-fix-lower-right-corner-of-div-to-screen-w-r-t-scroll-up-down)