# Is it possible to fix lower right corner of div to screen w.r.t scroll up/down

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to make div vertically expand when scroll down and vertically Contract when scroll up such that lower right corner approximately maintain same position on browser screen.

```
#resizable { 
position:relative; 
float:left; 
width: 300px; 
height: 200px; 
padding: 0.7em;
top:8px;
left:2px; 
word-wrap: break-word;}
```

div need to be relative and Adjustable to align all outer text wrap around it.

```
$(function() { $( "#resizable" ).resizable();});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYasQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this without fixed positioning using a bit of Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/EYasQ/5/

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
   var top = $(document).scrollTop();
   $("#resizable").css("marginTop", top);
});
```

The `scroll` event listener will update the top margin of the `#resizable` div whenever the page is scrolled. The div will appear to stay in place but the text will reflow around it. The effect is a little unusual, but it seems to match your requirements.

Comment: Oh @nullability i honor you for such a simple code, really you coded what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use position `fixed` for this:

```
#resizable { 
    position: fixed;
    ... 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYasQ/2/

Comment: in `position: fixed` the outer text is going back to div.i require no hiding of outer text.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed position instead of relative position. And since you want to have the div on the right hand bottom corner, please use the following:

```
position:fixed; 
float:right; 
bottom:8px;
right:2px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYasQ/3/

Comment: In `position: fixed` the outer text is going back to div.i hardly require no hiding of outer text.